# Build Time in VS2015 WAY Too Long, msbuild is fast

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a weird situation where any time I do a build of my solution, the build itself seems to take a short time (and in fact if I run msbuild in the command window it takes under 9 seconds), but then the IDE just sits there for about a minute, doing what I can't tell.  The fan on my laptop is spinning, and the IDE is completely non-responsive.  This happens every time I want to do something as simple as run a unit test.

The hanging occurs right after it gives me this line:

```
========== Rebuild All: 6 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thoughts as to what this might be or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: You should be able to get more info by setting Tools->Options->Projects and solutions->Build and run ->
‘MSBuild project build output verbosity’ = Verbose.
Also: what are you using to run the test? default test explorer?
Any special add-ins?

Comment: For comparison, what is the time to do a `msbuild /t:Rebuild` on the command line?

Comment: I'm using ReSharper's TestSessions/runner.  But even if I just do the standard "Rebuild Solution", it builds quickly and then sits there hanging forever.  I did crank up the verbosity level to "Diagnostic" and get a ton of information, however since the hanging occurs after the "Rebuild All:" message, there are no messages at all indicating why it's sitting still.

Comment: The straight "msbuild" command I ran took 8.94 seconds.  When I did your "/t" variation it took 10.06 seconds.

Comment: It happens when I do a simple "Clean" too

Comment: During builds in RESMON I see a few second spike in disk activity from msbuild, and then a half-dozen threads and a ton of activity from EntityFramework for the remainder of the time.  EF seems to be the culprit but not sure why.

Comment: Does this weird issue occur on the new blank project? And have you try to use devenv.exe /SafeMode, which allows you to run any version of visual studio (devenv.exe) in SafeMode that will disable 3rd party plugins. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: You can make it more faster by command below which uses all processors for building solution.

>msbuild /m /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug PathToSolutionFile.sln


Reference: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx